# The way of making UIStoryboard's custom UIComponent

Tags: ios, custom-controls

I want to make custom `UIComponent` to using in `UIStoryboard` or xib. There any way to make my custom component?
thanks :)

Custom component like UITableViewController :-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. Apple doesn't allow it.

Xcode 3 used to support interface builder plug-ins, but this feature was dropped this in Xcode 4.

What you can do:
You can use @IBInspactable properties to them on Identity Inspector window.
You can use @IBDesinable to show the UIView while making in storyboard.

for @IBDesignable or @IBInspectable read : [Tutorial](https://medium.com/anantha-krishnan-k-g/ibdesignable-and-ibinspectable-in-swift-3-702d7dd00ca)